# SQL Server 2014 - Optimizer does not use partitions on nonclustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-partitioning

I'm using SQL Server 2014, I have a huge table of 120 columns and more than 30 million rows. My clustered index is on a column of type `DATE`.

I created a partitioned function:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [20yearsDate](date) 
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'2015-07-07T00:00:00.000', N'2015-08-07T00:00:00.000', N'2015-09-07T00:00:00.000', N'2015-10-07T00:00:00.000', N'2015-11-07T00:00:00.000', N'2015-12-07T00:00:00.000', N'2016-01-07T00:00:00.000', N'2016-02-07T00:00:00.000', N'2016-03-07T00:00:00.000', N'2016-04-07T00:00:00.000', N'2016-05-07T00:00:00.000', N'2016-06-07T00:00:00.000'........etc............
```

*(its a partition per month)*

Now, when I'm  running a query where the `WHERE` statement is on the `date` column (the last 3 month), it uses a nonclustered index that partitioned on partition scheme:20yearsDate, on Column: Date.

BUT the problem is that the optimizer uses all 241 partitions!

Why doesn't it use a 3 or 4 partitions if my where statement is on the last 3 months?

Comment: Where is the `where clause`? Can we see it? In fact can we see the entire query, and the table definition? I.e. An MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: SELECT GI.a
    , GI.b
     FROM TableA GI WITH (FORCESEEK)
    INNER JOIN  GovIDs GPT
     ON GPT.ID =GI.eTypeID
  WHERE GI.Date BETWEEN '20160502' AND '20160707' -- The GI.Date is the clustered
     Group By GI.a
      , GI.b

is it ok?

Comment: Whenever you start using query hints you are telling the sql engine that you know better how it should query the data. Unless you are absolutely certain and your testing has proven that you need those hints you should probably just avoid them. And are your dates actually strings? If not, you should use the ANSI standard yyyy-mm-dd format to avoid any localization issues.

Comment: share query then only it can be identified why it is not picking partition..

Comment: Thank you for your answer:
the quary is very simple:
<Code> 
SELECT GI.CustomsItemID
    , GI.Declaration_OrganizationUnitID
     FROM  [FCT].[DealFile_fact_GoodsItem] GI
    WHERE GI.Date BETWEEN '20160502' AND '20160707' 
<Code>
the where clause is on the clustered index (date).